# Angular app: no typescript error when assigning a string to a number

Tags: angular, typescript

I had a bit of confusion today when my app was behaving strangely. Turns out I was assigning a string to a number, but there was no error alerting me of that. *Any idea why that might be?*

```
id:number;
```

later:

```
this.id = ActiveRoute.params.id; //(this was a string, obviously)
//do some iteration (n=this.id) times
```

My iteration was only running once, but I would have expected to be alerted to the type misalignment when assigning to id.

(edited attribute originally from memory^)

Comment: what is ActiveRoute? and what is props? angular-router uses ActivatedRoute.params

Comment: Going from memory since my work compy wasn't open, and those aren't the important parts. the important part is I defined a number in TS, and it let me assign a string to it without warning me.

Comment: Because it is typed as `any` not `string`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad `id:number;` is typed as `any`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming `ActiveRoute` is of type `ActivatedRouteSnapshot`, of which, the type of property `params` is `Params`, which meets the interface `{ [key: string]: any }`

that `any` part there is the important bit, TS doesn't know the type of the properties in the `Params` object, so it takes your word for it when you assign it to a property with type `number`. `any` really means TS will let you assign it to any type. You need to make sure you assign correctly.

docs: https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot#params